# Submitting app with iCloud enabled: is it possible? Apple: Invalid Code Signing Entitlements

Tags: ios, app-store, icloud, key-value-store, code-signing-entitlements

Two apps, say, AppX and AppXLite, use the same iCloud key-value storage with the same Store Identifier and in entitlements file I see $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.company.AppX

Everything works in adhoc and debug builds. But when I try to upload AppXLite to appstore, I get an error:

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The signature for your app bundle
>   contains entitlement values that are not supported. For the
>   com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement, the
>   first value in the array must consist of the prefix provided by Apple
>   in the provisioning profile followed by a bundle identifier suffix.
>   The bundle identifier must match the bundle identifier for one of your
>   apps or another app that you are permitted to use as the iCloud
>   container identifier. Specifically, value "YYXXXXXXYY.com.company.AppX"
>   for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" in
>   AppXLite is not supported.

Agree with this letter, but then everything is ok: prefix, provided by Apple, bundle identifier. If not, this won't work in adhoc build. But why do they say that things aren't right?

Yes, I know that there are tons of answers here, I read them. People say that one should disable iCloud support in app in provisioning portal to fix such issue. If I do this my apps will no longer see iCloud, but this is one of key features!

I have an idea that I should upload AppX first, before AppXLite, as both apps use AppX's bundle id as Store Identifier. But I've added both apps on provisioning portal, so appstore should know "the bundle identifier for one of my apps" as Apple stated in the letter.

Do anyone have experience of uploading iCloud-enabled apps to Appstore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you faced the same:

1. Kill all profiles in provisioning portal
2. Kill all profiles in Xcode and devices
3. Recreate all needed profiles (I've created dev, adhoc and appstore for each)
4. Download them manually and drag to Xcode.
5. Clean and rebuild all apps
6. Submit first app, which bundle id is shared between them as a Store Identifier of iCloud.
7. Submit all the rest apps.

Result: everything in "Waiting for review" state.

Comment: Point number 6 (Submit first app, which bundle id is shared) was the main piece of information for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, me to, the only piece of knowledge here is 6.